# Does the Merlin vacuum engine on SpaceX's Falcon 9 gimbal?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, attitude-determination-and-control, vacuum, gimbaled-engines

SpaceX uses the Merlin Vacuum engine on the second stage of the Falcon 9 launch vehicle. Does the merlin vacuum engine gimbal or does the second stage uses only nitrogen cold gas thrusters for attitude control?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Falcon Payload User's Guide](https://www.spacex.com/media/falcon-users-guide-2021-09.pdf) posted on the SpaceX website, the 2nd stage engine gimbals. (Emphasis mine)

[image]

Comment: Hah, I like that, the user guide. I can't even decipher my VCR's user guide to stop the time from flashing and that thing has a _user's_ guide! :p

Comment: @CGCampbell yah, it's 88 pages, and the one for my Canon printer is 1155 pages.

Comment: "This user’s guide is intended for pre-contract mission planning and for understanding SpaceX’s standard services. The user’s guide is not intended for detailed design use" while your VCR's one has to tell you just about everything

Comment: @user253751 these comments were essayed as jests.

Comment: I was more interested in the price list though: $67M for a launch

Comment: Can't wait for the SpaceX "build your mission" page... No, dammit, I _don't_ want heated leather seats, it's just not worth the million...

Comment: All you have to do is watch a video of a landing. You see the exhaust swiveling all over the place.

Comment: @JohnnyRobinson what does landing have to do with the 2nd stage engine?